# Using SFTP + make default start directory

Tags: linux, debian, sftp

At start, i would liek to sorry, i"m new in linux administration, but I"M learning fast, right now i got a problem with sftp (was searching 2 days, how to fix it, but nothing has help.).

Soo, let me explain all:
i got a SFTP server (i think i got it), i use it, to conect to my server (using WINSCP on windows). I also use SSH to use my server.
But, i wanted to add new user, and let it use SFTP, but it don"t work :O.

Soo, if i log-in as root, all work fine, but when i try, loging with a new user, it just disconect me at start.

How i add user?
useradd -m test
passwd test 
User is in passwd/his password in shadow. So all look fine, also i can log-in using the ssh, to use the user. But when i want login in SFTP as a test user, it just don"t work.

Soo, in short:
- I can log-in as root, but i can"t login as other accout with SFTP

*A new Debian System.

**When i log in, with test/new accout using ssh, it close the window :O, so i can just only login wtih root

Comment: Please edit your question and provide verbose logs from both the client and the server.

Comment: :O, how can i get them?

Comment: A bit of research would show you how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your user doesn't have an home directory. 
So may be a good start would be to create this home dir (like `/home/loginname/`), change the ownership with `chown` command and try again.

Adduser command doesn't create the home directory of the newly created user (if you didn't use the -m, --create-home option).